# The SQL query takes a long time to execute in the .NET application, but runs quickly when executed through SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

In our environment, there was an issue where the menu grid would produce an error and create a copy without completing the process. I implemented a solution that worked well locally, but when deployed to the test environment, the page took an unusually long time to load, possibly around 5 minutes.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertKeyMap]    
(    
    @KeyMapId int output,    
    @MealTypeId int,    
    --@SchoolId uniqueidentifier,    
    @MapName varchar(30),    
    --@SchoolTypeId int,    
    @MenuItemId int,    
    @SubscriptionTerminalId int,    
    @IsUsedForMealCombo bit,    
    @RegionId int,    
    @DayofWeek [int],    
    @UserId uniqueidentifier,    
    @Rows int,    
    @Columns int    
)    

AS    
DECLARE @UniqueMapName varchar(30) = @MapName  
DECLARE @Count int = 0   
--Check  if MapName already exist ,if yes set to new names 
WHILE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [KeyMap] WHERE MapName = @UniqueMapName)  
BEGIN  
    SET @Count = @Count + 1  
    SET @UniqueMapName = @MapName + '-' + CAST(@Count AS varchar(10))  
END  
  
-- Insert the record with the unique MapName value  
INSERT INTO [KeyMap]    
(    
    [MealTypeId],    
 --[SchoolId],    
    [MapName],    
 --[SchoolTypeId],    
    [MenuItemId],    
    [SubscriptionTerminalId],    
    [IsUsedForMealCombo],    
    [RegionId],    
    [DayofWeek],    
    [UserId],    
    [Rows],    
    [Columns],    
    [CreatedBy],    
    [CreatedOn]        
)    
VALUES    
(    
    @MealTypeId,    
 --@SchoolId,    
    @UniqueMapName,    
 --@SchoolTypeId,    
    @MenuItemId,    
    @SubscriptionTerminalId,    
    @IsUsedForMealCombo,    
    @RegionId,    
    @DayofWeek,    
    @UserId,    
    @Rows,    
    @Columns,    
    @UserId,    
    GETUTCDATE()    
)    

SET @KeyMapId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

I added this logic in existing logic not sure how to improve code this much time ,locally it's working fine and loading application very quick

I'm curious if there are any performance concerns when using a WHILE loop in SQL and how it might impact performance in certain scenarios. What would be the best approach to enhance search efficiency in such cases?
P:S : I added this logic to our existing code

```
DECLARE @UniqueMapName varchar(30) = @MapName  
DECLARE @Count int = 0   
--Check  if MapName already exist ,if yes set to new names 
WHILE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [KeyMap] WHERE MapName = @UniqueMapName)  
BEGIN  
    SET @Count = @Count + 1  
    SET @UniqueMapName = @MapName + '-' + CAST(@Count AS varchar(10))  
END
```

Comment: Check if you have MARS enabled in the connection string. Also have you run SSMS from the same machine and against the same environment as your app?

Comment: Looping is a total no-no in SQL if you want good performance. You are either suffering from parameter sniffing, or you have a much larger dataset in prod (or both).